# Why is it not possible in python to have an objects method return a tuple as argument in a new objects __init__ method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object, tuples

Why is it not possible to have an objects method return a tuple as argument in a new objects **init** method? Why does the following code not work and what needs to be done to make it work?

```
   class AcceptsTupleOnInit:
        def __init__(self,s,z):
            self.s = s
            self.z = z

    class ReturnsTuple:
        def return_tuple(self):
            return ("1", "2")

    r = ReturnsTuple()    
    a = AcceptsTupleOnInit(r.return_tuple())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AcceptsTupleOnInit` doesn't take a tuple as an argument; it takes two separate arguments. You would need to unpack the tuple first.

```
a = AcceptsTupleOnInit(*r.return_tuple())
```

Alternatively, define `__init__` to accept a tuple

```
def __init__(self, t):
    self.s = t[0]
    self.z = t[1]
```

or better, define an additional class method to unpack the tuple for you.

```
# usage:
# a = AcceptsTupleOnInit.from_tuple(r.return_tuple())
@classmethod
def from_tuple(cls, t):
    return cls(t[0], t[1])
```

In all three cases, it is your responsibility to provide a tuple with at least 2 values. The original definition of `__init__` requires that `return_tuple` provide a tuple of *exactly* 2 elements; the modified `__init__` and the class method are more flexible and will simply ignore additional elements. That's why I prefer the original `__init__` (it's precise about what it requires and accepts) with a class method that can sanitize the input tuple as necessary. You can choose to ignore `t[2:]`, or you can raise an exception if they are present.